# How to get a list of keywords leading to a specific page in Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to use Google Analytics API to get a simple list of search keywords that lead users to a certain page (e.g. `http://example.com/page.html`), so I can visualize them as a network graph and see which clusters they form.

Inside the user interface of GA itself this can be obtained if I choose

`Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages -> page.html`

and then also select `secondary dimension` of `Advertising -> Keywords`

I can't find, however, which parameters I should use to get this data in Google Analytics API.

Maybe somebody can help?

Thank you!

PS I'll be happy to share the results with you if I manage to find a solution (my software is open source, so you can use it as well).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) on **ga:pagepath** dimension.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxxxx&dimensions=ga:keyword&metrics=ga:sessions,ga:bouncerate,ga:pageviewspersession&sort=-ga:sessions&filters=ga:PagePath%3D@page.html&segment=gaid::-4&start-date=2015-03-02&end-date=2015-03-02&max-results=10
```

In this example I select many metrics, and put a filter that the page path had to contain **page.html**.